# Laravel Count and Group By Child Relationship

Tags: laravel, group-by, count, eloquent, relationship

I have two tables, one called `companies` and one called `leads`. Using Laravel's Eloquent I'd like to get a count of leads for each company. Which is pretty straight forward, but I also need to group these by the Leads status.

e.g.

Company A has

```
3 hot leads
2 cold leads
```

Company B has

```
6 cold leads
0 hot leads
```

---

`Companies` table has the following structure:

```
 id
 name
```

`Leads` table has the following structure

```
 id
 company_id
 status (hot, cold)
```

---

I have tried the following, which gets the count of leads out for each company, but this needs to be further grouped by the status of the leads

```
 DB::table('companies')
     ->selectRaw('companies.id, companies.name, COUNT(*) as count')
     ->join('leads', 'leads.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
     ->groupBy('id')
     ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

When using aggregates such as `count`, you need to make sure to group by all selected non-aggregate columns.

MySQL will usually let you get away with out doing this but the query results can come out being non-sensical.

```
$companies = DB::table('companies')
    ->select(['companies.name', 'leads.status', \DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count')])
    ->join('leads', 'leads.company_id', '=', 'companies.id')
    ->groupBy('companies.name', 'leads.status')
    ->get();
```

If you have multiple records in the companies table with the same name (but different ids), this will group all the counts together for each duplicate company name.  If that's the case, you should also select and group by `companies.id` as well.

If you want to key this by the company, and then by the status, the following should work...

```
$companies = $companies->groupBy('name')->map(function ($company) {
    return $company->groupBy('status')->map(function ($company) {
        return $company->first()['count'];
    });
});
```

Then you can use it like...

```
echo $companies['testCompanyName']['hot']; 
echo $companies['testCompanyName']['cold'];
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked perfectly. Any suggestions to get the data out so that I have an array of companies, then within each company the hot and cold counts?

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer, is something like this possible? (It doesn't work atm)

`select *,
 (select count(*) from `companies` inner join `leads` on `leads`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` where `leads`.`status` = 'cold') as cold_count,
 (select count(*) from `companies` inner join `leads` on `leads`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` where `leads`.`status` = 'warm') as warm_count,
 (select count(*) from `companies` inner join `leads` on `leads`.`company_id` = `companies`.`id` where `leads`.`status` = 'hot') as hot_count
from `companies` where `companies`.`deleted_at` is null`

Comment: Actually I've figured out a way of doing this in laravel using `withCount`, I have a relationship on the model for leads and then I set another relationship for coldleads, warmleads, etc